# How can I rename id in attribute table

Tags: qgis

I create a layer by my own and I would like to change the ID name, but I don't know how? Could someone please help?[image]

I shows NULL but I would like to change it to Times Square

I create XYZ of Google Maps, then I create a layer-> create new shapefile layer and add the line from times square to statue of liberty

Comment: Which data type does your field have?

Comment: I'm not asking about the vector type, but about the field type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the "pencil" icon to enable editing.

Type into the box.

Click the pencil again to disable editing.

Save changes.

This will not work if the ID field is numeric, because you can only put numbers in a numeric field. In this case you need to make a new field.

Click the pencil to enable editing.

Find and click the "create new field" icon in the tool bar.

Give it a name and make sure its not numeric - it should be text or char or varchar or something like that. Call it "ID2" or something meaningful like "placename".

Save, then you should see a new column in the attribute table.

This is all basic QGIS editing stuff which you should find in introductory QGIS tutorials.

Type in that box and save to update the shapefile.

Comment: It has worked out. Many thanks